# Retrieving list of products using messageChannel Service

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have two LWC components one is publishing the event and the other is subscribing. They both are working fine but after subscribing I want it to invoke the apex, but it couldn't return the output, as the input parameters are in JSON and I dont know how would I receive it in the apex.

```
//Subscribing Component

import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, subscribe, MessageContext, APPLICATION_SCOPE } from 'lightning/messageService';
import PRODUCTS_FILTERED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/ProductsFiltered__c';
import getProducts from '@salesforce/apex/PosProductController.getProducts';

export default class ProductTileList extends LightningElement {
    filters = {};
    subscription;

    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

    @wire(getProducts, { filters: '$filters'})
    products;

    connectedCallback() {
        // Subscribe to ProductsFiltered message
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            PRODUCTS_FILTERED_MESSAGE,
            (message) => this.handleFilterChange(message),
            { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
        );
        console.log(this.subscription);
    }
    handleFilterChange(message) {
        this.filters = { ...message.filters };
        //this.filters = message.filters.pricebookId;
        console.log('Handle Filter Change');
        console.log(this.filters);
    }
}

    //Apex

    public with sharing class PosProductController {
    public PosProductController() {

    }
    public class Filters {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String searchKey {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Decimal maxPrice {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String pricebookId {get; set;}
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<PricebookEntry> getProducts(String filters){
        Filters productFilter = new Filters();
        productFilter.pricebookId = filters;
        system.debug('Filters are');
        system.debug(filters);
        List<PriceBookEntry> productList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
        productList = [SELECT Product2.Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id =: filters];
        system.debug(productList);

        return null;
    }

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<Pricebook2> getPricebookList(){
        return[SELECT Id, Name FROM PriceBook2];
    }
}
```

As of now what I want when I change the picklist then it should invoke the apex method. I dont want any dynamic query.

Comment: Is your subscribing component getting the message? Is the handlefilterChange method firing? "filters" payload that you are passing is an object, but your apex method is expecting a string.

Comment: Yes I am getting a message Here is the console "Handle Filter Change
productTileList.js:4 {searchKey: "", maxPrice: "10000", pricebookId: "XXXXXXXXXXX"}"

Comment: It is also hitting my apex, but I don't know why it is not even print the debug statement
"11:31:46.0 (597586)|EXECUTION_STARTED
11:31:46.0 (605900)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|apex://PosProductController/ACTION$getProducts
11:31:46.0 (9876037)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|apex://PosProductController/ACTION$getProducts
11:31:46.0 (9907090)|EXECUTION_FINISHED"

Comment: Likely could be the mismatch of the type of variable being passed to Apex. Change this.filters = { ...message.filters } to this.filters = message.filters.pricebookId and change your method variable type to a single string.

Comment: Thanks Cyber Jus it worked. But I don't know why it is not working for this filters = { ...message.filters }, What if I multiple filters I want send them as an array. Could you please tell me how can we do this with wrapper class

Comment: The error has been resolved as I have made the wrapper class and it is working now]